# discord.py tree slash command Interaction fail

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to code a discord bot using discord.py,

But the bot returns "This interaction failed"! I even tried to print "test" in the python console but nothing returns.

[Bot returns: This interaction failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLrWO.png)

Here is the entirety of the code:

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import app_commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync()
    print("Ready!")

@tree.command(name = "test", description = "My first application Command")
async def testouille(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!")
    print("test")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: The command sent in the image is not the same as the one shown in the code. My guess is that it has not synced or your bot is not online to even receive any inputs.

Comment: oops, it seems the screenshot I posted is outdated, but I still get the same problem when executing /test

Comment: If the screenshot is not updated, then please do so. Only if you give all information others will be able to help you with your feedback!

Comment: Can you upload your output in the console when the bot starts?
also, you can add `print(f"Logged on as {client.user}")` to see what bot is online in your console

Answer (score 0):

The error shown in the Screenshot happens if you call a command to the bot which one does not exist anymore but is still shown as available in your discord chat.

Most of the time a quick fix would be to refresh the discord page in your browser (or restart the browser).

One reason why this can happen is when the slash command gets renamed/changed while you are on discord.